# How to allow MediaWiki to create Transclusion_Count/data pages

Tags: mediawiki, transclusion

I imported the Template:Notice from MediaWiki, but am getting the following error:

```
Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'Module:Transclusion_count/data/N' not found.
```

I'm understanding that these data files are generated somehow rather than being imported.  How do I get my MediaWiki instance to create these data files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data modules are not a MediaWiki feature. On Wikipedia, the data is updated by a bot. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Ahechtbot#Task_6

Comment: hmmm.... then I wonder why the import of the export is returning the error above